# Sum Qty by date on date-time field

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sum the qty built (PartNum), grouped by date, Lot & PartNum.

```
     Date      PartNum Lot  Qty
e.g. 2/15/13   1003    56   21  
     2/15/13   1007    23   12


SELECT
    `product_trans`.`PtID` AS `ID`,
    `product_trans`.`PtLot` AS `Lot`,
    `product_trans`.`PtRole` AS `Role`,
    `product_trans`.`PtPosted` AS `Posted`,
    `product_trans`.`PtStamp` AS `Stamped`,
    `product_trans`.`PtLine` AS `Line`,
    sum(`product_trans`.`PtQty`) AS `Qty`,
    `product_trans`.`PtPart` AS `Part`,
    `product_trans`.`PtPartNum` AS `PartNum`
FROM
    `product_trans`
GROUP BY
    `product_trans`.`PtStamp`,
    `product_trans`.`PtPartNum`,
    `product_trans`.`PtLot`
ORDER BY
    `product_trans`.`PtStamp`,
    `product_trans`.`PtPartNum`
```

The problem is that PtStamp is a date-time field. I need it grouped by the date, not the date-time.

I tried this:

```
GROUP BY
    CURDATE(`product_trans`.`PtStamp`),
    `product_trans`.`PtPartNum`,
    `product_trans`.`PtLot`
```

but no joy.

I know this is simple, but I can't see it.

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY DATE(PtStamp)` instead of `GROUP BY ptstamp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
DATE(`product_trans`.`PtStamp`)
```

**[MYSQL DATE Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)**